# dynamic_cast issue xcode

Tags: c++, ios, unity-game-engine, objective-c++, dynamic-cast

I am working on porting a game from visual studio to xcode the game was completely written in c++ and I am having some troubles with dynamic casting that I never had when running in visual studio. I am wondering if it is a compiler issue or some things are just not supported in the mac environment, any help will be greatly appreciated. Here is a stripped down version of the code that I am running in xcode which will crash when doing the dynamic_cast

```
class base {
public:
 int dm;
 virtual void vm(){}
 base(){}
};

class specific : public base {
public:
virtual void vm(){dm++;}
specific (){}
};

specific* sp = new specific();
base* b = (base*) sp;
specific * s = dynamic_cast< specific * >( b );
```

Comment: What kind of crash? Please post a crash log...

Comment: What error do you get? Compile or runtime?

Comment: @pmd No mention of Objective-C in the question. Even if this is iOS, it might be pure C++. And Objective-C is a **superset** of C, not a subset.

Comment: The app is a mixture between all, it is a Unity project if that helps. But I have objective C code and c++ code written and working through out the project

Comment: Then I'm re-tagging this question.  Xcode questions pertain to the IDE, not to code crashing under a certain environment.

Comment: @Macmade I will get that as soon as possible, I believe it is an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS but I will have to check, on the machine it we run it on. Which in my experience seems to do with memory issues.

Comment: This has severe syntax issues before being valid C++ code. In any case, [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/16c7177f0e0a8f6cce52d0a026175cbf) is a valid, compilable C++ example similar to your case that exhibits no error.

Comment: Your code runs for me on X-Code on Snow Leopard (if I take your last three lines and add them to a main method)

Comment: The tag unity is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set "Enable Runtime Type" = YES
Build setting > Apple LLVM 5.0 - Language - C++ 
In your xcode project.

hope this help.